# snap issue with fontsconfig on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, fonts, snap

Operating system: Ubuntu 20.04

I welcome any suggestion/solution to solve this issue.

Using snap, I can remove snaps but when I want to install any snap, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo snap install darktable 
[sudo] password for aaron: 
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "darktable" snap if present (run hook "configure": 
-----
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 6 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc: caching, new cache contents: 89 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/util: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cMap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 6 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/cantarell: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipafont-gothic: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipafont-mincho: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/malayalam: caching, new cache contents: 7 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto: caching, new cache contents: 28 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 53 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gargi: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gubbi: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Nakula: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Navilu: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Sahadeva: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Sarai: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/abyssinica: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arphic: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu: caching, new cache contents: 22 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/farsiweb: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-beng-extra: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-deva-extra: caching, new cache contents: 3 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-gujr-extra: caching, new cache contents: 5 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-guru-extra: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-kalapi: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-orya-extra: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-telu-extra: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-yrsa-rasa: caching, new cache contents: 10 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/kacst: caching, new cache contents: 15 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/kacst-one: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lao: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato: caching, new cache contents: 18 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation: caching, new cache contents: 16 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-assamese: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-bengali: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-devanagari: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-gujarati: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-kannada: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-malayalam: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-oriya: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-punjabi: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-tamil: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-tamil-classical: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-telugu: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/malayalam: caching, new cache contents: 10 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts: caching, new cache contents: 60 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/padauk: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/pagul: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/samyak: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/samyak-fonts: caching, new cache contents: 3 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/scheherazade: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/sinhala: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tibetan-machine: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tlwg: caching, new cache contents: 58 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-khmeros-core: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu: caching, new cache contents: 14 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/xmind: caching, new cache contents: 27 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 2 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/aaron/.local/share/fonts: "/home/aaron/.local/share/fonts": Permission denied
/var/snap/darktable/common/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/var/cache/fontconfig: not cleaning unwritable cache directory
/snap/darktable/63/gnome-platform/usr/bin/fc-cache: failed
-----)
```

More information

```
$ dpkg-query -W fontconfig fontconfig-config 
fontconfig  2.13.1-2ubuntu3
fontconfig-config   2.13.1-2ubuntu3
```

The following is the output of fontconfig.log

```
$ cat /var/log/fontconfig.log 
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 6 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc: caching, new cache contents: 89 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/util: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cMap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 5 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-cns1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-gb1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan2: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-korea1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 6 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/cantarell: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipafont-gothic: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipafont-mincho: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/malayalam: caching, new cache contents: 7 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto: caching, new cache contents: 28 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 53 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gargi: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gubbi: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Nakula: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Navilu: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Sahadeva: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Sarai: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/abyssinica: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arphic: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu: caching, new cache contents: 22 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/farsiweb: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-beng-extra: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-deva-extra: caching, new cache contents: 3 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-gujr-extra: caching, new cache contents: 5 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-guru-extra: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-kalapi: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-orya-extra: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-telu-extra: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-yrsa-rasa: caching, new cache contents: 10 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/kacst: caching, new cache contents: 15 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/kacst-one: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lao: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato: caching, new cache contents: 18 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation: caching, new cache contents: 16 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-assamese: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-bengali: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-devanagari: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-gujarati: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-kannada: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-malayalam: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-oriya: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-punjabi: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-tamil: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-tamil-classical: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-telugu: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/malayalam: caching, new cache contents: 10 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts: caching, new cache contents: 60 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/padauk: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/pagul: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/samyak: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/samyak-fonts: caching, new cache contents: 3 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/scheherazade: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/sinhala: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tibetan-machine: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tlwg: caching, new cache contents: 58 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-khmeros-core: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu: caching, new cache contents: 14 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/xmind: caching, new cache contents: 27 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 2 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cMap: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cmap: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/opentype: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/type1: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/X11/util: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-cns1: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-gb1: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan1: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan2: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-korea1: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/cantarell: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipafont-gothic: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipafont-mincho: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/malayalam: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gargi: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gubbi: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Nakula: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Navilu: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Sahadeva: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Sarai: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/abyssinica: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arphic: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/farsiweb: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-beng-extra: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-deva-extra: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-gujr-extra: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-guru-extra: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-kalapi: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-orya-extra: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-telu-extra: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-yrsa-rasa: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/kacst: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/kacst-one: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lao: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-assamese: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-bengali: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-devanagari: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-gujarati: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-kannada: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-malayalam: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-oriya: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-punjabi: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-tamil: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-tamil-classical: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-telugu: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/malayalam: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/padauk: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/pagul: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/samyak: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/samyak-fonts: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/scheherazade: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/sinhala: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tibetan-machine: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tlwg: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-khmeros-core: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/xmind: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large: skipping, looped directory detected
/var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
```

More information

```
$ ls -l /etc/fonts/fonts.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2876 Nov 13 14:10 /etc/fonts/fonts.conf
```

Comment: It looks like you edited `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` somehow. That might be it.

Comment: I have no idea. I didn't have any knowledge of the fonts.conf until today. That is why I am puzzled.
Later I went to remove/install the fontconfig package (apt purge fontconfig), but when I saw the number of packages would be removed along side of it, I just stepped back.
Well, it's late night here. I guess I will continue tomorrow with this.
Thanks Gunnar.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, you were absolutely right.
I copied a fonts.conf from a different machine, and ran diff command for both. There was a line which I modified long ago to include an extra font directory. Apparently snap does not have access permission to that folder.
I removed the line and it worked like a charm.
Thank you so much.
Problem solved.

Comment: So I have the same issue but the solution (copying from another machine) did not solve the problem. They were both unmodified 
`fontconfig 2.13.1-2ubuntu3
fontconfig-config 2.13.1-2ubuntu3`

Anyone has other suggestions? My result is that I can't seem to install any snaps any longer.

Comment: @Warner, did you check conf.avail and conf.d as well? Maybe something missing in these two folders.

Comment: @Warner, also check the permissions. Maybe Snap does not have permission to access the directories or files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I had the same issue. Here's how I solved it:

Move fonts to a temp folder:

```
sudo mv /etc/fonts/ /etc/fonts.bak
```

Reset the desktop:

```
dconf reset -f /
```

Reset permissions of existing fonts in shared folder:

```
find /usr/share/fonts -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
```

Reset permissions of existing fonts in user folder:

```
find ~/.fonts -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
```

Move fonts back to original folder:

```
sudo mv /etc/fonts.bak/ /etc/fonts
```

Reset font cache:

```
sudo fc-cache -r -v
```

Downside is that by resetting the desktop you will have to start over with any customization you have made there. Also, I'm by no means an expert but the above worked for me so I thought to share it.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Didn't even need to reset the desktop (I skipped that step on my machine).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with Ubuntu 20.04-LTS-Focal in WSL2 environment, while I was trying to install Adobe-Acrobat-Reader-DC through snap, which I assume it is happening because of the limitation in the current WSL version, which does not support Wayland-display yet (so far WSLg available for the developer channel only).

in addition snap/snapd is highly dependent on systemd and openssh-client. Any issue with those will be reflected on your snap environment.

```
$ sudo snap install acrordrdc
Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "acrordrdc"                                                                                                                                                
\
Run configure hook of "acrordrdc" snap if present                                                                                                                                                                 
\Run configure hook of "acrordrdc" snap if present                                                                                                                                                                 
|error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "acrordrdc" snap if present (run hook 
"configure":
-----
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 5: invalid 
attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 34: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 35: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 35: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 35: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 36: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 36: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 6 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc: caching, new cache contents: 89 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/util: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cMap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 5 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/cantarell: caching, new cache contents: 5 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/fonts-hosny-amiri: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/malayalam: caching, new cache contents: 7 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto:
<aborted>
-----)
$
```

Comment: please format what you pasted below the line as code... make use of the options at the top of the input editor field.

Comment: I fixed the above issue by fixing an ssh error I had. first I had to purge openssh* which will remove all the snap installed services in the process. Then I reinstalled the openssh-server and fixed the ssh service error, at this point both systemd and ssh were working properly with no errors (in my case I  had to change the ssl port to 4600 in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file). then I started reinstalling all the snap services I had including the Acrobat Reader, this time everything went flawlessly and the snap list is rock solid. cheers