# Snap error: Unable to install due to Fonts

Tags: software-installation, fonts, snap

So I've been getting this error when updating or installing Snaps:

```
$ sudo snap install snap-store
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "snap-store" snap if present (run hook "configure": 
-----
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
.....more of the same...
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 10 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts: /usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts: error scanning
.....more of the same...
/var/snap/snap-store/common/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/var/cache/fontconfig: not cleaning unwritable cache directory
/snap/snap-store/518/gnome-platform/usr/bin/fc-cache: failed
-----)
```

This happens with any Snap I tried.

Seems related to Fontsconfig (according to <[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319794/snap-issue-with-fontsconfig-on-ubuntu-20-04)>):

```
$ dpkg-query -W fontconfig fontconfig-config 
fontconfig  2.13.1-2ubuntu3
fontconfig-config   2.13.1-2ubuntu3
```

But the solution there (copying /etc/fonts/fonts.conf from another machine) doesn't have any effect here. Does anyone have suggestions for a solution?

Comment: Additional info: Even when installing Snaps that don't give an explicit error, there are issues with the fonts (making apps unusable). Any way to totally reset fontsconfig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to solve the issue. Here's how I did it:

Move fonts to a temp folder

```
sudo mv /etc/fonts/ /etc/fonts.bak
```

Reset the desktop:

```
dconf reset -f /
```

Reset permissions of existing fonts in shared folder:

```
find /usr/share/fonts -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
```

Reset permissions of existing fonts in user folder:

```
find ~/.fonts -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
```

Move fonts back to original folder:

```
sudo mv /etc/fonts.bak/ /etc/fonts
```

Reset font cache

```
sudo fc-cache -r -v
```

Downside is that by resetting the desktop you will have to start over with any customization you have made there. Also, I'm by no means an expert but the above worked for me so I thought to share it..